# Why do I get a System.FormatException converting a DateTime to an Int32

Tags: c#

Server Error in '/' Application.

Input string was not in a correct format.

*Description:* An unhanded exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

*Exception Details:* `System.FormatException`: Input string was not in a correct format.

*Source Error:*

```
Line 15: int i, j=0;   Line 16: j = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a date-time string to an integer?

Answer (score 2):

Trust your error messages!  If it says that the Input String is not in the correct format, it means it.  So check the Input String:

Check what `DateTime.Now.ToString()` returns.  If anything in that string is not interpretable as part of a number, the `Convert.ToInt32()` will fail.

Specifically the documentation for [Convert.ToInt32()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) says that a `FormatException` will be thrown when the value passed in "does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9)."